# I removed Windows 8 and installed Ubuntu 14.04, now my fn keys to manage brightness and volume don't work and I can't boot into BIOS

Tags: keyboard, brightness, bios

To clarify, this isn't a dual-boot, I just have Ubuntu now.

My FN keys are no longer working on my ASUS K55n, this includes changing my brightness and volume. I've already tried editing the GRUB file and adding acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendo, but that didn't work.

I also can't boot into my BIOS anymore. I've restarted my laptop and tried pressing F2, DEL, ESC, F10, and F8 and nothing works. It just loads straight to Ubuntu everytime, any ideas?